# Why does my code get a ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I am trying to make a window with OpenGL (using LWJGL 2) with Java. When I tried to run, a ClassNotFoundException error came up from the Eclipse 'BuiltInClassLoader'.

I have tried using different versions of LWJGL, changed the code and put everything in one class.

``
DisplayManager.java (excerpt)

```
private static final int WIDTH = 1280;
private static final int HEIGHT = 720;
private static final int FPS_CAP = 60;
private static final String TITLE = "Our First Display";


public static void createDisplay() {
    ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3, 2).withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true);
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);
        Display.setTitle(TITLE);
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}


public static void updateDisplay() {
    Display.sync(FPS_CAP);
    Display.update();
}


public static void closeDisplay() {
    Display.destroy();
}
```

MainGameLoop.java (excerpt)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DisplayManager.createDisplay();

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {


        DisplayManager.updateDisplay();
    }

    DisplayManager.closeDisplay();
}
```

I expected the output to show a window, this is the real output: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more`

Comment: Did you follow the Eclipse project setup directions on this page?
https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/1.2.-Install

Comment: I had the same issue. To fix it, I removed LWJGL3 from my build path and re-added it. Generic answer, I know, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried changing the JRE to 1.7 instead of 14 and it worked for me. Oh yeah and it might flicker a lot when the window comes up. To fix that just change the FPS_CAP to 120 instead of 60.

Answer (score 0):

locate the jar that contains org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW, and add that to Build Path to the project in Eclipse.